# Displaying information to 2 different listboxes - using trees

Tags: c#, forms, list, linked-list

I'm currently designing a form in C# and i'm trying to display information into two separate text boxes. As you can see when I click 'Add Artist' it adds the artist and number of artists into the same box. which I don't want it to do.

I know that the line 'listBox2.Items.Add(artist);' is causing this, however I don't know what to change it to so that it only display the number of members. My artist class is as follows:

I think I need to separate name and members within the first return statement so that I could display them separately by maybe using listBox2.Items.Add(artist.members); or something similar in the form class however I'm not sure.

Any help is appreciated! thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like when you create

`List<string> ListBoxItems = new List<string>();`, you're saving your what artist's `ToString` returns, which is:

```
(name + members);
```

---

There are a couple of things you can do, you can impliment `ListBoxItems` as a `List<Artist>`, and then you can build your list with the following:

```
foreach (string artist in ListBoxItems)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(artist.Name);
    listBox2.Items.Add(artist.Members);
}
```

Or, you can make 2 lists.  say `ListBoxNames` and `ListBoxMembers`, and populate them each with their respective fields.  I personally would prefer the first method.

OR, if `ArtistTree` impliments `IEnumerable`(hightlight it and press f12 to check) than you can just pull from that

```
foreach (Artist artist in ArtistTree)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(artist.Name);
    listBox2.Items.Add(artist.Members);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply sam :) I tried that just then but I get an error with the Members in artist.Members http://speedcap.net/sharing/screen.php?id=files/b8/de/b8dec4134b3cb830ea6e3b9a4dfeb6bd.png

Comment: @user2058186  I see, `ListBoxItems` is a list of `string`, You might want to implement it as a list of `Artist`

Comment: thanks for the reply, i'll accept that as the answer and try it myself :)

Comment: @user2058186 of what type is `ArtistTree`

Comment: @user2058186 is it a built-in data-type, or did you define it?

Answer (score 2):

listBox2.Items.Add(artist.Members);

Comment: thanks for the reply :) I think this would work if I was using a datadictionary however i'm using trees :/

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the DisplayMember property of the list boxes to be the public property of the Artist class that you want to be displayed.

You could include the following code on your form to achieve your objective:

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name";
listBox2.DisplayMember = "Members";
```

Comment: i've just tried it and it's not displaying any output to either of the listboxes, i've played around with it a bit by adding listBox1.DisplayMember = "Name" + name; on the end but still to no success